# Docker-compose uses wrong ASP.NET Core version (3.0 instead of 3.1)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

As the title suggests, docker-compose tries to build a 3.0 ASP.NET Core Image instead of 3.1.

I recently updated my project from 3.0 using the instructions from this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/30-to-31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio except the global.json part, since I don't use one.

Here is what I tried:

[image]

This is my yaml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    hraapi: 
        build: .
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        image: vmandeal/hra.api:testing
        container_name: hra.api
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        depends_on:
            - hradb
    hradb:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
        container_name: hra.api.db
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "YeyPass"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

And this is my project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Discovery.ClientCore" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: There should be a `Dockerfile` in your project. I guess there's the wrong base image tag used.

Comment: do you update your `Dockerfile` to use image with asp.net core 3.1?

Comment: Yep, "FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/publish ." so stupid. I totally ignored it. Thank you ChristophLütjen and Exploding Kitten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should recreate your docker file,

There is a `FROM` keyword in your docker file that shows your container should start with which image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MainApplication/MainApplication.csproj", "MainApplication/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MainApplication/MainApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MainApplication"
RUN dotnet build "MainApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MainApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MainApplication.dll"]
```

In `VisualStudio` simply right click on your project `Add-->Docker Support` to recreate your docker file.

[image]

Comment: Serious question.  Why use 3.1-buster-slim instead of just 3.1?  I don't understand the -slim.  I know the buster is a specific distro, but again why do I care?

Comment: You can use any other 3.1 image instead, you can even make your own, but this image is the recommended one by visual studio.